# VBA code to copy data from different works book to specific sheet of master workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, combine

I have to copy data from 15+ workbooks and combine it into a different master workbook. All these 15+ workbooks are identical and contains a sheet(tab) named 'Comment'  and have same header names for different columns.

The master workbook contains 7 sheets, but I am only interested in sheet ‘Master Comment” as  I want to copy the data from 15+ workbooks to this “Master Comment” sheet only. This “Master Comment” sheet also has the same column header name as 15+ workbooks.

All the workbooks are located in a same folder on my desktop.

So, I was wondering if someone could please help me to create a VBA code for this? I'm really new to VBA and would really appreciate your help!

Please let me know if you require any clarification.

Many thanks! =)

Comment: Welcome! You tagged the question with Excel-2010. Since you still don't know VBA, it makes sense to get acquainted with another tool - [**PowerQuery**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379). It is available for your version of Excel as an extension. With its help, combining the necessary data from different sources into one master sheet turns into an [**exciting game with the mouse**](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=power+query+combine+multiple+excel+files+from+folder) and you do not have to learn a programming language.